# Photon Voice not picking up Microsoft Hololens 2 Microphones

Tags: hololens, photon

So, for an application I am developing with my friend, we realized we needed voice chat. The application is multiplayer, and the networking and multiplayer aspects have been developed with PUN2, in Unity.

For voice chat, we opted for photon voice 2, and after following a few tutorials everything works fine on the computer ( voice echo, users speaking, hearing and talking to each other works fine).

The problem is, when I deploy the application prototype on Microsoft Hololens 2, no microphone input is detected from the headset, nothing comes out, and the speakers seem to not work as well (I can hear the UI sound effects of the windows menu etc.. but not the in-game speakers, from where the voice are emitted).

I have read on some forums that a special package is needed to make Photon Voice 2 work with HoloLens 2, and comes at a cost.

Is there any way to help debug or pickup voice inputs from the Microsoft HoloLens 2?
More generally, how do I access Microsoft HoloLens 2's speakers and microphone from the application in unity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HoloLens official sample indicates the usage of microphone and you may take the official demo as an example to develop your project – [WindowsMicrophoneStreamDemo](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/tree/main/Assets/MRTK/Examples/Demos/Audio/Scenes).

Please note that MRKT Microphone Stream Selector package is required for this sample and It can be imported easily via [Mixed Reality Feature Tools](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=102778)

Answer (score 0):

Hope you've already solved the problem.
You need to build for ARM, not ARM64 to use Photon Voice without special package.